# “Custom Field Template” plugin - first MULTIPLE FIELD FIELDSET disappears on save

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Custom Field Template plugin for my WordPress project. I have multiple field fieldset which allows to upload a photo and add title from the back end.

The problem: when ever I update the post first fieldset disappears and it keeps doing that until only one field set is left.

I would really appreciate some wise advice from you guys cause this issue is making me sick right now.

Plugin I use: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/

Functions.php file and template file is built according to this tutorial: http://www.kevinleary.net/multiple-fields-groups-wordpress-custom-field-template-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. Since I have seen couple more people with a similar issues I think I can help.

So If you are using CFT plugin for wordpress and your multy fieldsets gets wiped out if you add more than 2 of them just transfer them to another template and it works perfectly well...